# What exactly this accuracy loss value means? How to relate with input data?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

When model is trained, i got the below accuracy.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 2 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/1
3/3 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 5.3142 - acc: 0.6667
```

What exactly 5.3142 and 0.6667 means? how can i relate with this input data ?

Comment: This depends on the model which you are using. Loss function and accuracy metric are defined there.

Comment: I am using binary_crossentropy as loss function, adam as optimizer, and metrics=['accuracy'].

Comment: In this case 0.667 is a simple accuracy, this means that 66.67% of labels were predicted correctly. And binary cross-entropy means simple cross entropy:
ylna+(1−y)ln(1−a)
Here is an explanation about cross-entropy: https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/why-you-should-use-cross-entropy-error-instead-of-classification-error-or-mean-squared-error-for-neural-network-classifier-training/